# How to parse Redis Streams Data with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, redis-py

I need some help getting the message received by a Redis stream in python. For example if I send the following data through the stream:

```
{
  "identifier": "abcxyz"
  "query": "testQuery"
}
```

I receive the following from the stream:

```
[['streamA', [('1611593593691-0', {'identifier': 'zxkbdnarrz', 'query': 'testQuery'})]]]
```

Here is how I connect to the Redis Stream:

```
r1 = redis.Redis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port,
             password=redis_password, db=1, decode_responses=True)  

fromStreamA = r1.xread({'streamA': "$"}, count=1, block=0)
```

Ideally I would like to be able to access everything between the `{}` so that I can use the Python JSON module to access it as a dict.

How can I do this?
TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can do something like this:

```py
msg = [['streamA', [('1611593593691-0', {'identifier': 'zxkbdnarrz', 'query': 'testQuery'})]]]

[[stream, [[number, d]]]] = msg
print(d)
>>> {'identifier': 'zxkbdnarrz', 'query': 'testQuery'}
```

or when your Message look like this:

```
msg = [[b'streamA', [[b'1627026892700-0', [b'identifier', b'zxkbdnarrz', b'query', b'testQuery']]]]]
```

you can get the dict with this code:

```py
msg = [[b'streamA', [[b'1627026892700-0', [b'identifier', b'zxkbdnarrz', b'query', b'testQuery']]]]]

[[stream, [[number, parts]]]] = msg
foo = (p.decode('utf-8') for p in parts)
d = dict(zip(foo, foo))
print(d)
>>> {'identifier': 'zxkbdnarrz', 'query': 'testQuery'}
```